# What do I win for guessing the mimic?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've just arrived in Opelucid City and I've found a room where 4 children want me to identify the mimic. I've done so repeatedly for far too long. Am I wasting my time or is there a point to this very mini-game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, and from what I read [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/661226-pokemon-black-version-2/64358989), it's just for the sake of it. I tried like 20 times, and nothing. The person who posted on the link I gave said they tried for 10 minutes, and nothing special happens.